# Native file dialog for both folders and files on MacOs

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt, sandbox

I'm working on a Swing app, which will be run in the MacOs sandbox. In order to access files and folders on the file system, I need to use the native file chooser (not JFileChooser). I need to be able to select both files or folders.

I tried using `java.awt.FileDialog`. Unfortunately, by default it only selects files. If I provide the property `"apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories"` I can make it open folders, but then it can't open files.

```java
import java.awt.FileDialog;

FileDialog fileChooser = new FileDialog(null);
fileChooser.setMode(FileDialog.LOAD);
fileChooser.setTitle("Select file or folder");

// Setting this property, only folders are selectable
// Unsetting the property, and only files are selectable
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true"); 

fileChooser.setVisible(true);
```

How can I make `FileDialog` allow both folders and files? If it's not possible, what other ways are there to use the MacOs native file chooser from Java?

Comment: You can select both file or folders if you decide which, before invoking file chooser. Is it acceptable  ?

Comment: I'd prefer to have a single "Browse" button and let the user choose. Otherwise, I'll need 2 "Browse" buttons, which is not good experience.